# Java-fx - how to set background image in specific cell in treeview?

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I would like to design treeview cells. I'm able to set background in the all cells. But thats not what i want to do. I need to design specific cells

This code i have got to set background in the all cells in css file.

```
.tree-table-cell, cell{
-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);`
-fx-background-image: url("background_image.jpg");}
```

[All cells backgrounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJp6Q.png)

I need to set background for example in the third cell to something and the fourth to something else. Is it even posible target each of the cell?

```
 @FXML private TreeTableView<scheduledPosts> myTree;
@FXML private TreeTableColumn<scheduledPosts, String> col1;


TreeItem<scheduledPosts> post1 = new TreeItem<>(new scheduledPosts("post1"));
TreeItem<scheduledPosts> root = new TreeItem<>(new scheduledPosts("name of the post"));
```

init function->

```
@Override public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {     
    //getTimestamp();
    root.getChildren().setAll(post1);
    col1.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<scheduledPosts, String> param) -> param.getValue().getValue().getNameProperty());
    myTree.setRoot(root);
    myTree.setShowRoot(false);
```

Thanks for help.